# Voice recognition on iOS. Voice to Text

Tags: ios, voice-recognition

I have started looking into OpenEars and want to be able to grab certain words from the user.

e.g. The app asks "How are you" or "What is your name" or whatever, and the app then grabs the next word or series of words, and saves them to text.

So that the text can be identified later.

Is this possible with OpenEars or another api available for iOS that will still be approved by apple?

Thanks